# flowcover view alternatives (with uiwebview not with uiimage)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I tried fajowski's cover flow view. I was able to understand the most part of the changed the uiview to uiwebview. the problem now i am facing is the horizontal scroll is not working at all. This is because of webviews inserted into a scrollview.

> Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled.

source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

What i am asking for is this. Is there any other way where i can mimic the same flow cover view with a uiwebview without any horizontal scroll issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the web views to be interactable then you can likely just `myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` to fix your odd scrolling issues. This way, the web views won't trap any touch events that the scroll view should be getting.

Otherwise...hmmm no not really. If the above approach doesn't work you could try painting the web view to a graphics context and extracting an image from it, at which point you could use the stock flow component.